# Team Foundation Server 2008 managing Sql Server 2005 & 2008 database changes

Tags: tfs

Does anybody have any recommendations for managing database changes with Team System 2008 and Team Foundation Server 2008?  I am a developer for my company and was hoping to achieve source control over the database stored procedures, triggers, tables etc... with TFS 2008.

We are currently using TFS 2008 to manage our source code for our .Net projects.  We have Visual Studio Team System 2008 that contains the Architecture Edition, Database Edition, Development Edition and Test Edition.  I am not really familiar with the capabilities of the Database Edition.

I really appreciate any recommendations.

Just to let you guys know we will be using this for source control over 2005 and 2008 sql server databases.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [DB Ghost](http://www.innovartis.co.uk/) for out database change management. It does a good job capturing the entire database. They have a recommended flow for starting out and getting your db in source control.

That said, if you already have Team Suite, I would recommend using the built in tools. Here is a link to the [MSDN Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833220%28VS.80%29.aspx) type info for Team Edition Database.

Good luck, and congratulations on making the decision to version your database. It is a challenging process, but a very important one.

Answer (score 0):

With the database edition you can easily import you database objects and add the objects into source control. When you develop your database, you can do that from within the database project and then deploy the changes to sql server.

See also the Database Guide from the Visual Studio ALM Rangers: http://vsdatabaseguide.codeplex.com/